# How can i run a background calculation after a certain reason was given discord.py

Tags: discord.py, background-task

I made a bot that if someone runs a command then 3 points will be deducted from a thing called 'energy'. The max energy is 10 and if a user runs out of energy, then he cant run anymore commands. For this reason i wanted to make it such that if the energy points decreased below 10 the bot will automatically add 1 point every 10 seconds. But i dont know the correct way to do so.

Note: I am using json for saving the values and doing in discord.py. Below is my code:

```py
async def energy():
        tasks.loop
        statistics = await update_stats(ctx.author)
        while statistics[0] < 10:
            await asyncio.sleep(10
           
users_stats[str(user.id)]['energy'] += 1
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated :D